# MongoDB querying array slow

Tags: mongodb

We're trying to optimise our read performance on our MongoDB cluster.
We serve a social media like application where users are member of 1 or multiple groups.

We were storing who is in which group and whether he/she is an admin of that group in a separate collection. However we noticed it was quite slow to retrieve the group information for the groups the user is member of. (find(+filter) groupMember documents, populate the groups).

Therefor we recently migrated all the group members to an array on the group collection documents itself.

The schema now looks as following:
[image]

The query we execute is simply:

```
this.model.find({
 members: {
   $elemMatch: {
     userId: new ObjectId(userId),
   },
 },
})
```

We expected this to be much more performed because you don't need to populate/lookup anything. The opposite is true however, after deploying this change we noticed a performance decrease.

We have around 40k group documents where the largest groups have around 3k members, most groups are much smaller however.

The groups are indexed and the index is also used. This is an explain plan:

```
{
  "explainVersion": "1",
  "queryPlanner": {
    "namespace": "***.groups",
    "indexFilterSet": false,
    "parsedQuery": {
      "members": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "userId": {
            "$eq": "61b091ee9b50220e75208eb6"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "queryHash": "DCF50157",
    "planCacheKey": "DCF50157",
    "maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached": false,
    "maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached": false,
    "maxScansToExplodeReached": false,
    "winningPlan": {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "filter": {
        "members": {
          "$elemMatch": {
            "userId": {
              "$eq": "61b091ee9b50220e75208eb6"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "keyPattern": {
          "members.userId": 1
        },
        "indexName": "members.userId_1",
        "isMultiKey": true,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "members.userId": [
            "members"
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": 2,
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "members.userId": [
            "[ObjectId('61b091ee9b50220e75208eb6'), ObjectId('61b091ee9b50220e75208eb6')]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "rejectedPlans": []
  },
  "executionStats": {
    "executionSuccess": true,
    "nReturned": 17,
    "executionTimeMillis": 0,
    "totalKeysExamined": 17,
    "totalDocsExamined": 17,
    "executionStages": {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "filter": {
        "members": {
          "$elemMatch": {
            "userId": {
              "$eq": "61b091ee9b50220e75208eb6"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "nReturned": 17,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
      "works": 18,
      "advanced": 17,
      "needTime": 0,
      "needYield": 0,
      "saveState": 0,
      "restoreState": 0,
      "isEOF": 1,
      "docsExamined": 17,
      "alreadyHasObj": 0,
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "nReturned": 17,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
        "works": 18,
        "advanced": 17,
        "needTime": 0,
        "needYield": 0,
        "saveState": 0,
        "restoreState": 0,
        "isEOF": 1,
        "keyPattern": {
          "members.userId": 1
        },
        "indexName": "members.userId_1",
        "isMultiKey": true,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "members.userId": [
            "members"
          ]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": 2,
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "members.userId": [
            "[ObjectId('61b091ee9b50220e75208eb6'), ObjectId('61b091ee9b50220e75208eb6')]"
          ]
        },
        "keysExamined": 17,
        "seeks": 1,
        "dupsTested": 17,
        "dupsDropped": 0
      }
    },
    "allPlansExecution": []
  },
  "command": {
    "find": "groups",
    "filter": {
      "members": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "userId": "61b091ee9b50220e75208eb6"
        }
      }
    },
    "projection": {},
    "readConcern": {
      "level": "majority"
    },
    "$db": "***"
  },
  "serverInfo": {
    "host": "***",
    "port": 27017,
    "version": "6.0.3",
    "gitVersion": "f803681c3ae19817d31958965850193de067c516"
  },
  "serverParameters": {
    "internalQueryFacetBufferSizeBytes": 104857600,
    "internalQueryFacetMaxOutputDocSizeBytes": 104857600,
    "internalLookupStageIntermediateDocumentMaxSizeBytes": 104857600,
    "internalDocumentSourceGroupMaxMemoryBytes": 104857600,
    "internalQueryMaxBlockingSortMemoryUsageBytes": 104857600,
    "internalQueryProhibitBlockingMergeOnMongoS": 0,
    "internalQueryMaxAddToSetBytes": 104857600,
    "internalDocumentSourceSetWindowFieldsMaxMemoryBytes": 104857600
  },
  "ok": 1,
  "operationTime": {
    "$timestamp": "7168789227251957761"
  }
}
```

Under load the query takes 300-400ms, which is not acceptable for us.

However right now we don't really know anymore what would be the best next step in improving the solution. Mongo does not advise any additional indexes or schema improvements at this moment.

What can we do best to get this query really performand?

Comment: This explain plan indicates that the operation can execute efficiently with the given index. So the slowness is coming from "something else". Are you seeing elevated disk/cache usage under load? Is the concurrency write heavy? Do the reads mostly look like this or are there other types of queries that are common?

Comment: We measure the performance within our (nodejs) codebase. So it includes network delays, but there both mongo as our ec2s are running in same data center that should be mimimal. Also the response is small, the group document is not that large and users are only in 10-20 groups.

The data hardly changes, maybe an additional member a day or so.

Comment: Network is an important consideration which indeed is not reflected in explain output. But if the overall size and shape of the result set that you are transferring back from the query hasn't changed (has it?), then I wouldn't expect network to suddenly become the bottleneck.

Comment: I agree, it must be something else.